# Need help understanding printf code in bash

Tags: bash

I'm working on a project and I don't have much bash experience and need some help understanding the following string. I looked up printf syntax but it didn't help much either. Thanks!

```
 "\0\0\0\0\0\x9\x1\x10\0\0\0\01\02%b%b"
```

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with here? Have you looked at the bash manual entry for [printf](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-printf)?

Comment: I need help understanding what is going on with that string. I know that \xNN is for hex but I'm not too sure about \0 and the two %b's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`help printf` shows

> %b        expand backslash escape sequences in the corresponding argument

So, for example

```
 printf "\0\0\0\0\0\x9\x1\x10\0\0\0\01\02%b%b" '\1' '\xff' | xxd
```

returns

```
00000000: 0000 0000 0009 0110 0000 0001 0201 ff    ...............
```

i.e. `%b%b` interprets backslashes in the given arguments and returns characters whose codes are `01` and `ff`, respectively.